# How to route pakets from an aliased interface towards a gateway?

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm having trouble setting up the following:

```
Router IP: 192.168.1.1

PC
Eth0 - 192.168.1.104
Eth0:1 - 10.0.0.1 (must be an alias)
```

Besides `ip_forward enabled`, what should I add to iptables rules, so that computers on the network 10.0.0.0 and 10.0.0.1 gateway, to access the internet?

I guess a `POSTROUTING` and a `FORWARD` and would be added, but I can not configure it.

Comment: Do you have GUI?

Comment: @martincanaval If you edit a post anyway, please also remove unwanted parts like thanks (appreciation/greetings/username etc.)